# TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When I fetching the object from the collection i am getting the TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.report.Object2.obj3 -> com.report.Object3

Below is my object structure:

```
@Table( name = "TAB1" )
Class Object1 {

... fields

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "field", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
private List<Object2> obj2List;

}

@Table( name = "TAB2" )
Class Object2 {

... fields

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "J_ID", referencedColumnName = "J_ID" )
private Object3 obj3;
}

@Table( name = "TAB3" )
Class Object3 {

... fields

@Column( name = "J_ID" )
private Long jId;

}
```

Note: I am not inserting any records with this. It is only getting the records from DB.

So, I am fetching the Object1 from DB and i am taking the Object3 from list of Object2s.
When I call the getter of the Object3 from Object2, I am getting this exception.

Please suggest me if I am missing somthing here and Why this exception occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your criteria/hql, it will be helpful.

Comment: I am Using JPA with Annotations.